# Multiple filter is not working in AWS server showing some depreciation issue but it is working fine in localhost. How to solve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I am very new to Vue js. In the user listing page, there are 2 types of filter.

- Enter keyword to search
- Choose Location from the dropdown to search

I am able to search with any one option among the above 2 but I need to search with both of them accordingly.

Following is the code what I tried to do the combined search:

```
// == Enter keyword to search ==//
<input type="text" id="search" v-on:keyup="filterTable()" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Keyword"/>
// == Enter keyword to search ==//

// == Choose Location from the dropdown to search ==//
<select class="form-control" v-model="location_filter">
  <option value="">View all locations Associated</option>
  @verbatim
     <option v-for="loc in locations" :value="loc.id">{{loc.organizationName}}</option>
  @endverbatim
</select>
// == Choose Location from the dropdown to search ==//

//== Table to show listing ==//
<b-table ref="table" :sort-compare="tableSort" class="table-light" :filter="table_filter" striped hover light bordered :items="items" :fields="fields" show-empty></b-table>
//== Table to show listing ==//

//== Vue script ==//
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  window.app = new Vue({
    el: '.vue',
    methods: {
      filterTable: function (e) {
        if(e) e.preventDefault();
        this.table_filter = function (value) {
           let search_filter = $('#search').val();
           let type_filter = $('#search_type').val();
           if (search_filter != null) {
              let re = new RegExp(search_filter,"gi");
              return (app.location_filter == null || app.location_filter == "" || value.locationId == app.location_filter) && (search_filter == "" || re.test(value.name));
            } else
               return (type_filter == null || type_filter == "" || value.userType == type_filter);    
          };
        }
     },
     data: {
    location_filter: {!!$location_filter!!},
    search_filter: null,
    table_filter: null,
    locations: JSON.parse('@json($locations)'),
     }
   });
});
//== Vue script ==//
```

But when I run this code, in localhost it is working fine but in the AWS server, it is showing the error "**[BootstrapVue warn]: b-table: Supplying a function to prop "filter" is deprecated. Use "filter-function" instead.**" So I tried with filter-function too but nothing happens. Then I tried the followgin code:

```
// == Enter keyword to search ==//
<input type="search" id="search" v-model="filter" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Keyword To Search" style="margin-left: 10px;"/>
// == Enter keyword to search ==//

// == Choose Location from the dropdown to search ==//
<select class="form-control" v-model="location_filter">
  <option value="">View all locations Associated</option>
  @verbatim
     <option v-for="loc in locations" :value="loc.id">{{loc.organizationName}}</option>
  @endverbatim
</select>
// == Choose Location from the dropdown to search ==//

//== Table to show listing ==//
<b-table ref="table" class="table-light" :filter="filter" striped hover light bordered :items="items" :fields="fields" show-empty></b-table>
//== Table to show listing ==//

//== Vue script ==//
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  window.app = new Vue({
    el: '.vue',
     data: {
    location_filter: {!!$location_filter!!},
    search_filter: null,
    filter: null,
    locations: JSON.parse('@json($locations)'),
     }
   });
});
//== Vue script ==//
```

This code is wokring on the AWS server but it is doing only one search but I need to do search with the both.Any suggestions what do I do now? 
Thanks in advance!!